# Apply mulitple patches from a directory using msysgit

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

When I run the following command to apply multiple patches located in `/c/tmp/patches` **msysgit** hangs:

```
git.exe am --3way --signoff --directory=/c/tmp/patches/
```

I am using version 1.7.8-preview20111206.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue in msysgit?

Comment: Is it using cpu?  Is it waiting for input?  Is it doing any disc io?  procmon will tell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Cannot tell if it is waiting for input but CPU and disk IO is idling.

Comment: For me on Git-1.9.5-preview20150319, `git am` just quits silently, even if I pass `-i` (interactive) flag. But maybe I'm doing something wrong - my patch files do not contain commit information, but only diff sections.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `--directory` switch is for specifying the target directory to apply the patch relative to and is not for telling it a directory containing patch files. According to the [am documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) it passes the `--directory` option to the apply command (see also [`apply --directory` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---directoryltrootgt)).

On Windows 10 `git apply --3way ./.patches/*.patch` runs fine in Git Bash (applies multiple patch files).

However that does not in powershell, CMD or Git CMD - I get `error: can't open patch './.patches/*.patch': No such file or directory` even though `dir ./.patches/*.patch` correctly lists the files. Not sure why (would like to know).

Comment: Sorry, thought this was only 6 months old, not 10 years and 6 months! Didn't see that part... Anyway, for anyone searching still might be useful.